# How to properly deal with editable complex object (nested) with vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Vuex is really nice to display complex data, and do complex mutations (like adding a node to a tree with repercussions all across the store etc.), However, to me, it feels like a pain in the ass dealing with "simple" mutations on complex objects.

One use case I'm facing is (quite) simple : I have a component that displays a list object (with nested properties and arrays). Each properties are editable. Each object is displayed with a subcomponent. (and I need to use v-model on leaf properties)

The other use case is a modal dialog that is opened using a component's method, that will permit to edit some properties / nested properties of the object (and also, I needs to use v-model on leaf properties)

Currently, This is what I do :
In the components that display / edit an object, I put in the component's `data` a "skeleton" of the objects that could be edited (an object with all nested properties present, but all leaf set to `null`). Then, when the modal open, or the component should display / make editable an object, I simply deep copy the object (using a recursive function) to the `data` one, and I watch the data one with `deep` option to `true`, and commit on each change.

This feels a bit wrong, and needs quite an effort to make it work.

I like the mutation traceability system, and what I would like is to commit my whole object each time a modification is done on a nested property. That would be really great if it was possible without writing such an amount of code (I'm wondering if it wouldn't be worthy to simply give up vuex for a simple global Vue Componnent store... and trade off the nice mutation system for simple code)

So is there a "standard" way or a "recommended way" ...Or simply a "smart" way to do it without requiring such an effort ?

Example of store state :

```
state = {
  foo : [
    bar : {
      users : [
        {
          name : '',
          adddr : '',
          needs : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          baz : [
            {
              k1 : v1,
              k2 : v2,
              k3 : [1,2,3,4,5],
            },
            //...
          ]
        },
        //...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

...And I would like to commit each time whole user.

Comment: Can you please post some examples of your Vuex instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... This problem pissed me off so hard that I wrote a module to handle all these complex cases. One can find it here : https://github.com/hl037/vue-data-proxy

Then, one could simply write this kind of componnent :

```js
import vueDataProxy from "vue-data-proxy";

export default {
  props : {
    user_ind;
  }
  computed : {
    ...vueDataProxy({
      user : {
        fetch() {
          return this.$store.state.foo.bar.users[this.user_ind];
        },
        commit(val){
          // here, val is the full object (if reactivity injected)
          // returned by fetch
          this.$store.commit('updateUser', {ind : this.user_ind, val}
        }
     }
  },
  //...
}
```

...Supposing you have a mutation called `updateUser(state, {ind, val}) { /*...*/ }`

...Then, it will commit on each modification at any depth

Comment: This is very interesting! My problem is that my state object is not deeply nested but contains a bunch of `bar[]` and `foo[]` where each `bar` and `foo` is also object. Each array will either 0 or many elements. I found it very messy to add and remove element from each array depending on user interaction of adding/removing data on the UI. Any tip here?

Comment: I think using vuex with vueJS 3 is actually a bit overkill for almost any usecase... It seems much easier and simpler in my sense to use the composition api's `setup()` and for each sub-state you would have in your vuex store, create a js/ts global and reactive object as store in a dedicated file, add a global getter function to return this object. Then require this file/getter anyway you need it. That way, it is clear what component use what store etc. If you need tracing the mutation, just log the accesses by returning a custom getter...

Comment: I am using vuex with Vue2. Heard of vue3 composition api but don't really know much about it. I doubt we will ever migrate to vue3 since it's just too much risk.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use on this way:

1. The component contains the full path of the property to be updated (this will be fired)
2. In vuex use lodash or another similar tool to set the property using the full path.

**Component**

```html
<template>
        <input v-on:change="update(‘object.nested.more.nested.attribute’, $event)" v-text:value="object.nested.mote.nested.attribute"></span>
</template>


<script>
 export default  {
  methods: {
    update: function (property, value) {
      this.$store.dispatch(UPDATE_COMPLEX_OBJECT, {property, value})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**VUEX**

```html
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
   myObject: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    [UPDATE_COMPLEX_OBJECT] (state, data) {
      _.set(state.myObject, data.property, data.value)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    [UPDATE_COMPLEX_OBJECT]: ({commit}, data) => {
      commit(UPDATE_COMPLEX_OBJECT, data)
    }
  }

}
```

Let me know if something is not clear and hope this help you.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it is gonna update,  but how do you bind the value to the input then ? (anyway, I think it is more "hacky" than my current solution)

Comment: Hi, you need to create a simple component, this needs to be the minor possible representation, for example the leaf.
Check Vuetifyjs, the have an expandable list that probably can help you.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists.
Check the Expansion Lists

Answer (score 0):

Pretend you have a complex nested object like the following one:

```
{
  super: {
    nested: {
      object: {
        to: {
          be: {
            updated: 'foo'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you may want to have an action which updates a specific key:

```
import * as types        from '../mutation-types'
import * as defaultStore from '../defaultStore'

export default {

  namespaced: true,

  state: defaultStore.complexObject,

  getters: {
    getSettings: state => state
  },

  mutations: {
    [types.UPDATE_SUPER_NESTED_OBJECT] (state, payload) {
      state.super.nested.object.to.be.updated = payload
    }
  },

  actions: {
    updateSuperNestedObject (store, payload) {
      return store.commit(types.UPDATE_SUPER_NESTED_OBJECT, payload)
    }
  }

}
```

In your component:

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

 computed: {
   ...mapActions('<modulename>', ['updateSuperNestedObject'])
 }

 methods: {
   handleUpdate(payload) {
     return this.updateSuperNestedObject('bar')
   }
 }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: no, you target only the leaf. I want to commit a whole "sub tree" keeping the reactivity (but I added an example to illustrate it, and (event if it's random data) "complex" enough to justify I can't afford making mutation for each key